# Mutate column based on match to a vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got a vector of characters, which looks like this:

```
> head(vc)
[1] "0012" "100" "1001" "1003" "1005" "107"
```

I also have a dataframe, which looks like this:

```
code  city
0012  ty
987   ch
1005  ny
111   al
```

I want to add a column to my dataframe, where, if a given `code` is found in `vc`, then the column will say 'yes', and if it is not, it will say 'no'. Something like this:

```
code  city  viable
0012  ty    yes
987   ch    no
1005  ny    yes
111   al    no
```

Also, the datasets are big (+ 1million rows), so I need an efficient way of doing this matching.

Answer (score 2):

It will be something like this.
(If you provide a `dput` of data I could be sure but this is a freestyle answer)

```
df['viable'] <- ifelse(df$code %in% vc,"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would aim at putting the information in your data.frame. Try

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(code = c(0012,987,1005,111), city = c("ty","ch","ny","al"))

df %>% mutate(variable = if_else(city %in% c("ty", "ny"), "yes", "no"))
```

For more complex conditions you may use `case_when()`

Comment: @ Motoko M. Probably written too fast. Do you mean '%in% vc'?

Answer (score 1):

We may do this without `ifelse`

```
df$viable <- c("no", "yes")[1 +(df$code %in% vc)]
```